# Replace substring with edited substring

Tags: javascript, regex

please, could you help me with my task: I need to replace part of string and probably the best way is regular expression but I don't know, how to make it working. I want to do this:

```
http://someweb.com/section/&limit=10&page=2
```

replace `page=2` with `page=3` so string will be:

```
http://someweb.com/section/&limit=10&page=3
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
// set string in t variable
t.replace('/page=[0-9]/', 'page=$1++') });
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You have a string as your first argument in your replace, you'd need a regex i.e. /page/ not '/page/'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our case first argument should be regexp, but in your variant this is string `'/page=[0-9]/'` (remove `'`). In [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) you can pass function as second argument, and do with matched data what you want. (for example add `+1` to `page=`)

```
var str = "http://someweb.com/section/&limit=10&page=2";

str.replace(/page=(\d+)/, function (match, page) {
  return 'page=' + (+page + 1); // plus before page converts string to number
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/rataco/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Jan Kožušník maybe like this http://jsbin.com/jaruq/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below code.

```
var url = "http://someweb.com/section/&limit=10&page=2",
    reExp = /page=([0-9])+/,
    result = reExp.exec(url);

url = url.replace(reExp, 'page=' + (+result[1] + 1));
console.log(url)
```

Comment: It can separate page=XX but it won't increase number :/

Comment: EDIT: Work, I just wrote `url.replace(reExp, 'page=' + (+result[1] + 1));` and result didn't insert into variable...

Comment: Its working fine. I have checked in firefox console and chrome console also. @JanKožušník, it is increasing number, I am converted result with number and then added 1.

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote. My fail. I'm sorry